# Injecting dataSource class to presenter gives null

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm trying to inject `DataSource` class to `Presenter` using Dagger 2, but dataSource is null.

The code is below :

```
public class MainPresenter implements MainMVP.Presenter {

public static final String TAG = "MAIN-PRESENTER";

@NonNull
private MainMVP.View mainView;

@Inject
DataSource dataSource;

public MainPresenter(@NonNull MainMVP.View mainView) {
    this.mainView = mainView;

    Log.i(TAG, "MainPresenter init");
    DaggerDataComponent.builder()
            .dataModule(new DataModule())
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onButtonClick() {
    if (dataSource != null) {
        mainView.showData(dataSource.getReleaseString());
    }
}

}
```

If I remove the condition that checks for null in dataSource I'm getting a `NullPointerException`. Anyone can help with that? Isn't the constructor the right place to build the `DataComponent` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're building your component but you don't seem to be actually using it.

```
DataCompontent component = DaggerDataComponent.builder()
            .dataModule(new DataModule())
            .build();
component.inject(this);
```

and add

```
void inject(MainPresenter presenter);
```

to your `DataComponent` interface.

---

As for your question about if that is the right place to build your component: we can't really answer that. That strongly depends on your code architecture.

[Here's a nice example of MVP + dagger2 architecture.](https://github.com/ribot/android-boilerplate) Maybe try following that.